# how to load scripts into html page in openshift project?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, openshift

I tried to host a node project using openshift. In HTML page I wanted to load script, it was in my 'js' folder.

i did that in normal way like below, but it was not worked.

```html
<script type="text/html" src="/js/particles.js"></script>
```

Is there any special way to load scripts in openshift projects?

link to my GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/manushakaru/nodejs-ex)!

Comment: The answer to this depends on what container image you are using and how it hosts your static files. It is likely that the web server you are using is hosting your files at a different path.

Comment: Hello @Nick, I followed [link](https://docs.openshift.com/online/getting_started/basic_walkthrough.html#getting-started-basic-walkthrough) tutorial for getting started.

Comment: I hosted my js code using [http://yourjavascript.com/](http://yourjavascript.com/) then I used that as the source but it also not worked. @Nick

Comment: Can you provide the error message that your webpage is throwing?

Comment: There is no error message but it was not able to appear what i expected. @Nick